# NSOpenPanel - exclude startup disk

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

Using NsOpenPanel, I would like to exclude the startup disk from the dialog (grey out). If not possible, I would like to get the path to the startup disk ("/Volumes/Macintosh HD" most of the time but not always) as an URL. I have not found anything related to startup disk and swift on the net. Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the path to the startup disk is always `/`

To disable the URL in the panel adopt `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` and implement

```
func panel(_ sender: Any,
           shouldEnable url: URL) -> Bool {
    return url.path != "/"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, that's why I am talking about the startup disk and not the root folder. I want to compare it to an url starting with : "/Volumes/..." and I cannot use the root path. The NSOpenSavePanelDelegate solution seems very appropriate. I'll let you know. Thank you.

Comment: The root folder is equal to the path to the current startup disk

Comment: I should have look earlier at the answer of my dialog box when selecting the root folder. I would have noticed that the answer is "/" and that I just have to put a condition to reject it. Implementing NSOpenSavePanelDelegate is a better answer but I don't find complete examples to do it properly. Any suggestion? Cheers.